# CSS Selector Case Insenstive

Tags: html, css

I am having issues using Stylish to skin a site but the image values given are not all the same case. I will get some images with Cattle.GIF, Cattle.gif or cattle.GIF. Right now, I have it working for one set of the images but the others will not work.

```
img[src*="cattle"] {
    height: 00 !important;
    width: 1 !important;
    /* these numbers match the new image's dimensions */

    padding-left: 41px !important;
    padding-top: 35px !important;
    background: url(https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/resonantriseimages/resources/CattleIcon.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

Above will only work if the word is all lower case. I am trying to make it so it doesn't care if it is capital or lowercase.

Comment: any chance you could use javascript? It is much easier that way.

Comment: When it's supported, you should be able to use `img[src*="cattle" i]`.. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case

Comment: @t3dodson that question relates to using jQuery which the OP hasn't specified. I guess he's looking for a CSS only solution, of which there isn't really one.

Comment: I dont know if Stylish support javascript. I think I would have to use tampermonkey or something of the like.

Comment: There's no easy way—you will either have to rely on JS to convert the attributes to lowercase, or manually go through all possible permutations in CSS alone (which is unnecessarily tedious).

Comment: @Terry: I may have to do that but trying to keep the code clean the short.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: It looks like Stylish doesnt support the i

Comment: @Ryahn Then yes, you will have to do the JS way.

Comment: @Terry: Thanks, looks like I will have to learn a little JS.

Thanks everyone